# How do I sort_by in Ruby without the initial prepopsition (a, the, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a series of manufacturers and some of them use "The" at the beginning of their official name. People refer to them by the actual name, and looking in a `select` for the name under "M" but it's under "T"

e.g. The Moritz Embroidery Company

I was looking at taking each name, converting it to an array with `.split(" ")` and dropping "the" (`.delete("The")`) and then joining again, and THEN sorting, but that just seems the wrong way to do this.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "looking in a select".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was looking at taking each name, converting it to an array with .split(" ") and dropping "the" (.delete("The")) and then joining again, and THEN sorting, but that just seems the wrong way to do this.

This is called the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and it is what powers ruby's sort_by.

(*shamelessly <strike>stealing</strike>copying some of @mudasobwa's code*)

```
 input = ["The Moritz", "A Moritz", "The Embroidery Company"]
 input.sort # => naive sort, ["A Moritz", "The Embroidery Company", "The Moritz"]
 input.sort_by { |str| str.gsub(/\A(The|A)\s+/, '') } # sort without prepositions
 # => ["The Embroidery Company", "The Moritz", "A Moritz"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive info on Schwartzian transformation.

Comment: Am I the only one who is puzzled by such a simple concept as "sort-by" being named after a person? Surely coders were performing  "Schwartzian transformations" long before it was given that moniker.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: no idea about that one. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland From the Wikipedia link:

"The idiom is named after Randal L. Schwartz, who first demonstrated it in Perl shortly after the release of Perl 5 in 1994. The term "Schwartzian transform" applied solely to Perl programming for a number of years, but it has later been adopted by some users of other languages, such as Python, to refer to similar idioms in those languages. However, the algorithm was already in use in other languages (under no specific name) before it was popularized among the Perl community in the form of that particular idiom by Schwartz."

Comment: Also, FWIW for those who want to do this in ActiveRecord, my implementation in the Rails project:

`@manufacturers = Manufacturer.all.sort_by { |man| man.name.gsub(/\A(A|The)\s+/, '').to_s }`

Comment: @JohnAthayde: this implementation doesn't use any of the activerecord :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) with explicitly defined `\A` anchor for the matches at the beginning of string only:

```
input = ["The Moritz", "Not The Embroidery Company"]
input.map { |str| str.gsub(/\AThe\s+/, '') }
#⇒ ["Moritz", "Not The Embroidery Company"]
```

One-liner for sorting inplace:

```
input.sort_by { |str| str.gsub!(/\AThe\s+/, '').to_s }
#⇒ ["Moritz", "Not The Embroidery Company"]
```

Please note, that the latter mutates an original array.

Comment: destructive `gsub!` is unnecessary there, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It depends on whether we want to return the original array or the one without prepositions.